# Calculating the roots of cubic polynomial

Tags: calculus

**Q.** $F(x)= x^3+ ax^2 +bx+ c$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are real numbers. Suppose $c<0$, $a+b+c>-1$ and $a-b+c>1$ then what can we conclude about its roots.

**Ans.** I know that $f(-1)>0$, $f(0)<0$ and $f(1)>0$ so it has two real root one positive and other negative. But what about the third root is it real or imaginary?

Comment: Hint: can a real polynomial have one single complex non-real root?

Comment: Complex roots occur in pairs.  Slipped my mind. Thanks

Comment: Right. Now think what happens for very large $x$, positive or negative, and you'll figure out where the third real root is.

Comment: @dxiv By my calculations, for reasonably sized $a,b,c$ such that their absolute values are at most $11!!!!!!!!!$, then the root shall lie between $x=-1$ and $x=-\text{Graham's number}$ :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That's always true, for suitable values of Graham's number ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There are three roots.

If the third root is not real, but the other two roots are real, it follows that the sum of the roots is not real. However, $-a$ is a real number, so this is a contradiction.

We can also ascertain that there are three roots. If it has two roots, than $f(x)$ is of the form $$f(x)=(x-\alpha)^2(x-\beta)$$
Then $f(0)=-\alpha^2 \beta<0$, $f(1)=(1-\alpha)^2(1-\beta)>0$, $f(-1)=(-1-\alpha)^2(-1-\beta)>0$. So we have $$\beta>0, 1>\beta , -1>\beta$$ 
Which is a contradiction.